# php division results in zero (updated - issue was elsewhere)

Tags: php, wordpress

UPDATE - the problem was actually completely out of the rounding function.  It seems as though $price (used in woo commerce) is a string and for some reason I can't use it in a calculation.  If I simply return $price, no problem.  All of this was fine when I was simply returning the value of the other function.

```
 function xa_only_sale_price($price, $product)
{    
error_log ("price in the beginning is " . $price);
if(!is_cart() && !is_checkout() && !is_ajax()){
    if ($product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('variation')) {
        $price = regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product);
        $val = (float)$price; 
        error_log( "ceiling = " . ceil($val* 2) / 2);  // 0 printed to log
       return ceil($val* 2) / 2;  this returns 0

       // return roundNum(regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product));
    } 
}
  error_log ("price before call is " . $price);      // this returns 0
  // return roundNum($price);   //this is never in use
```

}
--------------- original post-----------------------------

I am new to php - thank you for all of the help in advance.  I am assuming that this issue has something to do with data types but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

In this example $num is the price of a woocommerce product.   If I simply return $num I see the price that I am expecting to see.  I am simply trying to round the value in this function (I simplified the function for the sake of the question).

```
function roundNum($num){ 
    $nearest = 0.50;
    return ($num / $nearest) ;
```

This returns 0 to the browser.  However, forcing the value of $num results in a valid calculation and return.

```
function roundNum($num){ 
    $num = 100.0;
    $nearest = 0.50;
   return ($num / $nearest) ;
```

Comment: what does `error_log(var_dump($num,true));` show you, from within the function? (output will be in your error log file)

Comment: @Nick *great minds....*

Comment: @Martin, yes, I deleted mine cos you got there first!

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it took me a minute to find out where that is (I'd been meaning to look into this more).   After the date/time it shows a null for all entries.  I put the call in the first line of the roundNum function.

Comment: This means the value `$num` is never set so whatever function *calls* the value is not being given the correct one. *That* will be your issue. Your function code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to typecast your input. A small example in your case is:

```
function roundNum($num){ 
    $nearest = 0.50;
    $result = (float) $num/ (float) $nearest;
    return $result;
}
```

Read more about typecasting [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Thank you for this!  Unfortunately I am still getting 0 as a result after copying/pasting in your exact code.

Comment: @AdamMorgan I believe there is something wrong with your set up. See the output of the code [here](https://3v4l.org/paf4k)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As it turns out your `$num` is a string. You can change this to a type `float` and make your calculations, like so:

```
$num = "48.2";
$float = (float)$num;
echo ceil($float * 2) / 2;
```

In this example your number is always rounded up by 0.5, so in this case to 48.5

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mOhhZ)

Comment: I am actually trying to round up to the nearest 50 cents.   Once I realized it was not working I slimmed down the function to the point of the real issue (I can't use $num)

Comment: then use ceil() like so: `$price = 48.6;
echo ceil($price * 2) / 2;` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is essentially just shifting around the problem.  The problem is that I can't seem to do any calculations using $num.  I tried using your code but I had the same result - 0.  Once again, if I simply return $num I can see that I do have a value of some type as I get the number back that I was expecting to see.

Comment: Could you tell the type of $num with  `print gettype($num);` ?

Comment: error_log(print gettype($num));

returns 1, but is that valid syntax in this language?

Comment: just try it without the `error_log()`, so just print out the type with the function i mentioned above.

Comment: Hmmm, it is saying that $num is a string.  Wouldn't float have taken care of that?

Comment: yes, typecasting this takes care of it. You can see my updated answer which will hopefully gives you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks again Dirk, I really appreciate your help.  Something very very odd is going on here. 

 If I return $num instead of your calculation I see the price on the product page.  

If I try to print out the value of $num I get null.  Val is also returned as 0.
   echo "val = " . ceil($float * 2) / 2 . " num = " . $num;
    error_log("val = " . ceil($float * 2) / 2 . " num = " . $num);
    return $num;

Comment: @dirk-j-faber I think that the problem is actually in the area of the code that calls the roundNum function.  

This code returns the actual price with no problem (no rounding).  

return regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product);

If I put that line of code (minus the return) into roundNum this is where $num is 0.

Comment: It's not all odd I think. Your `$num` simply is a string, so if you display it, it looks alright, but it still is a string so calculations with it isn't going to work. Try to get rid of all your functions and simply go: `$val = (float)$num; echo ceil($val* 2) / 2;` anywhere after `$num` is defined. I changed `float` to `val` to make it better understandable.

Comment: Here is one more example with two different functions where you can input bot a string (first one) and a float (second one): https://3v4l.org/p00Dm

Comment: I am still not sure that this is the issue.   I took your code and modified it a bit so as not to even new the roundNum function.  The result of this code is that "ceiling" (and the calculation) equals zero.

            $price = regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product);
            $val = (float)$price; 
            error_log( "ceiling = " . ceil($val* 2) / 2);

Comment: It would help if you post as much as your code as possible so that your problem is reproducible. I have the feeling you are creating a lot of variables with strings in them for now reason, but I can't tell without seeing what you did exactly.

Comment: That's part of the problem, I think - most of this is inside wordpress and I am simply trying to manipulate the various hooks.  I updated the original post with the current code.

Comment: You'll have to find out what this does `$price = regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product);` because I think it is messing up your variable. `var_dump($price)` in the next line or write it to your log and see what that does.

Comment: Here it is.          function regularPriceHTML_for_simple_and_variation_product($price, $product){
    return wc_price($product->get_price());
}

Comment: I think I found the problem.   The returned value of the function was not a number.  The function that I just inserted returned the price inside of html for display to the screen.   I believe I need to put the rounding inside of THAT function.    I'll test in the morning.

Comment: I really hope you found the solution :)